# How can we show $\text E\left[\left(\frac1t\int_0^tf(X_s){\rm d}s\right)^2\right]=\frac2{t^2}\int_0^t\int_0^s\text E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]{\rm d}r{\rm d}s$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued identically distributed product measurable process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\operatorname E[|f(X_0)|^2]<\infty$.

How can we show that $$\operatorname E\left[\left(\frac1t\int_0^tf(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right)^2\right]=\frac2{t^2}\int_0^t\int_0^s\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm d}s\tag1?$$

I don't know how we obtain $(1)$, but we've obviously got $$\operatorname E\left[\left(\frac1t\int_0^tf(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right)^2\right]=\frac1{t^2}\int_0^t\int_0^t\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm d}s\tag2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^t\int_0^t\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm d}=\int_0^t\int_0^s\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm d}+\int_0^t\int_s^t\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm ds}.\,\,\,\,  (1)$$ In the  second term apply Fubini's Theorem.  It becomes  $$\int_0^t\int_0^r\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}s\:{\rm dr}.$$ Changing  $(r,s)$ to $(s,r)$ we get $$\int_0^t\int_0^s\operatorname E[f(X_r)f(X_s)]\:{\rm d}r\:{\rm ds}.$$ So the two terms in (1) are equal  and sum is twice the first term.